# Import Data from a URL File Query into an Excel Sheet with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have made a URL of a file and I am able to make a query which returns me that CSV-file and I save it as an Excel file (.xls). This works fine. My problem is that I download several files and I want them all into the same Excel file so right know I save all those files and after that I copy them into a common Excel file... My code for each dowload file:

```
    XMLPage.Open "Get", URL, False
    XMLPage.send

    FileData = XMLPage.responseBody

    Set XMLPage = Nothing

    'Save the file

    FileNum = FreeFile
    Open carpeta For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
         Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
    Close #FileNum
```

I have in 'URL' the URL to my file, and in 'carpeta' the filepath where I want to save it. As I said, this works, but if I run:

```
   Debug.print XMLPage.responsetext
```

I already can see the information I want, separated by ";" (CSV format). My problem is that I am unable to copy this XMLPage.responsetext into a Sheet of my Workbook (even if it seems easier than the previous steps...).

I leave you an example of XMLPage.responsetext:

```
   "text1";"text2";"text3";"text4"
   "text5";"text6";"text7";"text8"
```

So instead of saving all those files I would only like to put this XMLPage.responsetext in my Excel sheets.

Comment: why not use `range(..).value = XMLPage.responsetext`?

Comment: Can you share an URL? Or more of the source code?